# Set expire date to temporary link of Dropbox api

Tags: php, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

Now I'm using Dropbox API v2 with `curl` + PHP to get a temporary link of files.

Does anyone know how to set the expire date of these links?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to creating links using [/2/files/get_temporary_link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link), it's not possible to explicitly set the expiration. These links always expire after four hours.

For paid accounts, you can set an arbitrary expiration on shared links using [/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings). Note that this is different than temporary links, e.g., in that these shared links show up to users on their [shared links page](https://www.dropbox.com/share/links).